# Java enum inheritance: Is it possible to somehow extract the enums' toString() method to a common super class/enum?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

I have 4 different classes with a common superlass called `WebService` that each have the following enums declared in them (with different values):

```
public class GeoPlacesService extends WebService {

public enum RequestParam {
    LOCATION, RADIUS, SENSOR, KEY;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return super.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}

public enum ResponseParam {
    STATUS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, NAME;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return super.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
}
}
```

Is it possible to somehow extract the enums' toString() method to a common super class/enum? Right now, I have to duplicate the toString() 8 times for each enum...

Comment: You could make your enum constants lower case if you feel that is how they should be natrually display, then your toString() wouldn't be required.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I was thinking about that, but doesn't that go against java coding conventions? (constants should be upper case)

Comment: They should, but the first rule should be to; do what you believe is clearest and simplest.

Comment: If you can, you should make your enums private.  Then you can dispense with java coding conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by others, you cannot have enums inherit from a common class.  If you are doing something more complex than you are showing in your sample code, then you could have some sort of a helper function that is static somewhere that takes in the enum and does the calculations.  Enums CAN implement an interface, so you can handle complex common toStrings that way potentially.

Comment: I ended up declaring a protected interface in `WebServie` called `Param` which has one method `toString`. This is implemented by all enums. I also wrote a static protected `toString` helper function in WebService that takes a `Param`.

Comment: You probably don't need the interface then, since all Objects (even Enums) have a toString method on them - so you are simply doing an override.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are final and also can't inherit from anything, so no. The best you can do is override toString() and delegate to a common "to-stringer" implementation so that you don't have to write the actual implementation over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Because `enum` has no inheritance model available to you, you can't extend anything from your `enum` class, and therefore..